# how to reconcile PDB structures' sequences via Uniprot references?

Tags: bioinformatics, sequence-analysis, pdb

I’m trying to reconcile structures  in PDB entries with their  sequences as reported in their `chemList.polymer.dbref` entries.

E.g.: considering structures for HIV integrase:

`PDB:3OS0` references `UNP:P14350`, focusing on integrase (len=391)

```
>sp|P14350|752-1143
CNTKKPNLDAELDQLLQGHYIKGYPKQYTYFLEDGKVKVSRPEGVKIIPPQSDRQKIVLQ…NRTVSIDNLKPTSHQNGTTNDTATMDHLEKNE
```

`PDB:2B4J` references `UNP:P12497`, focusing on integrase (len=287)

```
>sp|P12497|1148-1435
FLDGIDKAQEEHEKYHSNWRAMASDFNLPPVVAKEIVASCDKCQLKGEAMHGQVDCSPGI…LLWKGEGAVVIQDNSDIKVVPRRKAKIIRDYGKQMAGDDCVASRQDED
```

Why should these sequences be so different?!

and in case you think I'm focused on a bit of noise: there are **42 other** HIV integrase structures all referencing `UNP:P14350`, and **43 other** structures referencing `UNP:12497` (and 79 others referencing `UNP:Q76353`, very similar to `UNP:12497`), 22 referencing an entirely different `UNP:Q72498`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them is integrase:

```
P12497
Protein    Gag-Pol polyprotein
Gene       gag-pol
Organism   Human immunodeficiency virus type 1 group M subtype B (isolate NY5) (HIV-1)
```

```
P14350
Protein    Pro-Pol polyprotein
Gene       pol
Organism   Human spumaretrovirus (SFVcpz(hu)) (Human foamy virus)
```

Even if you meant the integrase product of the polyprotein, the second one is not even HIV.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_foamy_virus):

> Human Foamy Virus (HFV) is a retrovirus and specifically belongs to
>   the genera Spumavirus. The spumaviruses are complex and significantly
>   different from the other six genera of retroviruses in several ways.
>   The foamy viruses derive their name from the characteristic ‘foamy’
>   appearance of the cytopathic effect (CPE) induced in the cells.<sup>[1]</sup>

Comment: good catch, @wysiwyg!  first, yes, i have been focusing on just the integrase bit of the polyprotein (eg, that's what the `1148-1435` BLAST qualifier does).  and  i've purposefly been including PFV in my analysis because ["... PFV is very similar to HIV integrase and provides an excellent model for studies of retroviral integration"](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/101/motm.do?momID=135).  but obviously i need to check organisms before aligning their sequences!  thanks again for your answer.